# Can I use setTimeout instead of a click handler?

Tags: javascript

Here is my question. I'm working on a simple modal project. As it can be seen in the code, it calls the modal screen when the user clicks on the demo link or button.

However instead of clicking I would like to call that modal screen automatically after a certain time, like 20 seconds later. So can I actually apply `setTimeout` in that JavaScript code?

HTML

```
<div id='content'>
<div id='basic-modal'>

<input type='button' name='basic' value='DEMO' class='basic'/> 
<a href='#' class='basic'>DEMO</a>

</div>

<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<a href='asdasdasd'><img src="https:/asdasd.jpg" alt="asdasd"></a>

</div>
<div style='display:none'>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function(){ // Make sure jQuery is ready before delaying the modal function
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    }, (20 * 1000)); // Executes function in 20 seconds
});
```

Comment: setTimeout counts milliseconds. Therefor *1000

Comment: Exactly, that's what 20 * 1000 is for. I find it always easier to read when you write down 20 seconds as (20 * 1000) and 20 minutes as (20 * 60 * 1000).

Answer (score 0):

You want to still have the click event right? So you need to have it open after 20 seconds OR when someone clicks. Either way you will have to cancel out the timeout.

Here's the JS Code.

```
var timeout;
var openModal = function() {
  $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};

var delay = 20000; //20 seconds
timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  openModal();
},dealy);

$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function(e) {
  openModal();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Your `setTimeout` could be shortened to `setTimeout(openModal, delay)`. You're not gaining anything with the anonymous function.

Comment: That's true, but I have it put that way so it won't be confusing to the less experienced JavaScript coders.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#basic-modal-content').delay(20000).modal();
});
```

Comment: Are you asking or answering?

Comment: Looks to me like you're asking a question or you don't really know if your answer is correct.

Comment: No, I just don't know if this is what he was looking for

Comment: Here's the trouble. The `.delay()` method only works if the next method is automatically queued internally. For example, This will work `$("#foo").delay(1000).animate({height:1000})` but this will not `$("#foo").delay(1000).css({height:1000})`. So the question would be whether `.modal()` is queued internally.